# TensorFlow - ValueError: Shapes (3, 1) and (4, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I'm completely new to DL and I'm stuck with this error when I fit my model

`ValueError: Shapes (3, 1) and (4, 3) are incompatible`

Dataset:

```
Features: [0.22222222 0.625      0.06779661 0.04166667], Target: [1 0 0]
Features: [0.16666667 0.41666667 0.06779661 0.04166667], Target: [1 0 0]
Features: [0.11111111 0.5        0.05084746 0.04166667], Target: [1 0 0]
Features: [0.08333333 0.45833333 0.08474576 0.04166667], Target: [1 0 0]
Features: [0.19444444 0.66666667 0.06779661 0.04166667], Target: [1 0 0]
```

Model:

````
def build_fc_model():
  fc_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
  ])
  return fc_model```
````

Error at model.fit

```
model = build_fc_model()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-1), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

BATCH_SIZE = 10
EPOCHS = 5

model.fit(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code **InputLayer** is missing in **build_fc_model** so check this out:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_fc_model():
  fc_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((4,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
  ])
  return fc_model


data = np.array([[0.22222222, 0.625,      0.06779661, 0.04166667], 
                 [0.16666667, 0.41666667, 0.06779661, 0.04166667],
                 [0.11111111, 0.5 ,       0.05084746, 0.04166667], 
                 [0.08333333, 0.45833333, 0.08474576, 0.04166667], 
                 [0.19444444, 0.66666667, 0.06779661, 0.04166667]])

target = np.array([[1, 0 ,0],
                   [1, 0 ,0],
                   [1, 0 ,0],
                   [1, 0 ,0],
                   [1, 0 ,0]])

model = build_fc_model()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-1), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

BATCH_SIZE = 1
EPOCHS = 5

model.fit(data, target, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 991us/step - loss: 0.8198 - accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 2/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 603us/step - loss: 0.1590 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 593us/step - loss: 0.0372 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 597us/step - loss: 0.0131 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 680us/step - loss: 0.0064 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

Comment: Problem was in my dataset, I've no idea why.... I created a datafrane with pandas and then converted to tf dataset

Comment: If the problem is not reproducible, or was caused by a typo, the question should be deleted altogether